# How to obtain overline to a blank character?

Tags: phantom, overline

I tried the $\overline{\phantom}$, but it doesn't work. The output should look like this.

[[image]]

This can also included between single quotes.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR08g.png):

Answer (score 6):

`\phantom` had to have an argument, for example

```
$\overline{\phantom{I}}$
```

For it you can define `\newcommand`, for example as is done in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\newcommand\Bar{$\overline{\phantom{I}}$}

\begin{document}
text \Bar text
\end{document}
```

[image]